# form button deleting data by clicking it, how would I check if the likes or dislikes has been hit(differentiating the two)?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, if-statement, button

My web page is a forum where users can post text and images, then have them displayed on the web page. There is a like and dislike button that is output with each post. Everything works fine except when I hit the like or dislike button the post deletes itself; however, the likes are saved in my database, so I can tell there's nothing wrong with my queries, so is there something wrong with my form?

Here it is,

```
//not full file
if (isset($_GET['postid'])) 
{

    if (!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM dry_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']))) 
    {
           connect::query('UPDATE dry_posts SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
           connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_likes VALUES (null, :postid)', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
    } 



    if (!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM dry_dislikes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']))) 
    {
           connect::query('UPDATE dry_posts SET dislikes=dislikes+1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
           connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_dislikes VALUES (null, :postid)', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
    } 

}


$dbposts = connect::query('SELECT * FROM dry_posts ORDER BY id DESC');
$posts = "";

foreach($dbposts as $p){
        if (!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM dry_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$p['id']))&&!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM dry_dislikes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$p['id']))) {
                $posts .="<img src='".$p['postimg']."'>".htmlspecialchars($p['body'])."
                <form action='try.php?postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                        <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like'>
                        <span>".$p['likes']." likes</span>
                        <input type='submit' name='dislike' value='Dislike'>
                        <span>".$p['dislikes']." dislikes</span>
                </form>
                <hr /></br />
                ";

        } 

}
```

Here's the form

```
<form action='try.php' class = "forum" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="postbody" rows="4" cols="60" class = "text">

</textarea>
         <br />Upload an image:
        <input type="file" name="postimg">
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
</form>

<div class="posts">
        <?php echo $posts;?>
</div>
```

Comment: You have not posted the schema of your DB tables incl. constraints so this is only a guess, but if I would need to guess I would guess  that it is possible to like posts that do not exist.

Comment: I encourage you to make your request's simple. So for example: `try.php?id=*&job=like` and `try.php?id=*&job=dislike` and `try.php?id=*&job=delete`. Easy to link and maintain ( you dont need post request anymore as you dont have csrf token ).

Comment: @hakre after I post it will show on the page and save in my table, and will stay unless I hit the like or dislike button then the page will refresh with the post removed, but will remain in my database table. so the posts would have to be there

Comment: umm do a code search for `Delete` if post is actually deleting only delete query can delete i believe. above piece of code doesn't suggest if post is getting deleted.

Comment: @Coderanonymous ok I'm sorry what I really mean is that the posts are disappearing from the web page whenever the like or dislike buttons are clicked.

Comment: check the logic of displaying them, check if conditions are fine..check if on clicking like or dislike there isn't js event getting triggered to delete the post

Comment: @MoeinPorkamel I should change the url in my foreach loop?

Comment: nothing executes within the if statement where I check if the postid is set, I tried switching it to POST method but that didn't help.@Coderanonymous

Comment: @Coderanonymous nvm that if statement works fine and I'm not using any javascript

Comment: how would I check if the likes or dislikes has been hit(differentiating the two)? what should the condition be?

Comment: @Bubba: Just read your code again after some break. From what I see this is exactly what you have programmed. Posts that have entries in the like and the dislike tables (or whatever the false return value means for the db function) you don't want any of these posts to show. Looks like a flaw in the overall logic of the script if that is unwanted, hope this is pointing you into the right direction.